# Zip two lists in clojure into list of concatenated strings

Tags: list, clojure

Instead of zip-mapping two lists to get:

```
(zipmap ["a","b","c"] ["c","d","e"]) = {"c" "e", "b" "d", "a" "c"}
```

I want to concatenate the first element of the first list with the first element of the second list and so on to get:

```
("ce","bd","ac")
```

or in the reverse order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with `map`. `map` can take multiple collections, it takes the next element from each collection and passes them into the function passed as the first argument (stopping when one of the collections runs out). So you can pass in a function that takes n arguments, and n collections.

The expression

```
(map str ["a" "b" "c"] ["c" "d" "e"])
```

will call `str` first with "a" and "c", then with "b" and "d", then with "c" and "e". The result will be

```
("ac" "bd" "ce")
```

Since `str` can takes a variable number of arguments it can be used with any number of collections. Passing in four collections, like

```
(map str ["a" "b" "c"] ["d" "e" "f"] ["g" "h" "i"] ["j" "k" "l"])
```

will evaluate to

```
("adgj" "behk" "cfil")
```

Comment: Or `(map str ["a" "b" "c"] ["c" "d" "e"])`

Comment: Good answer. It relies on knowing how map deals with multiple collections, which doesn't always seem to be covered in tutorials.

Comment: Even if `str` took a max of two arguments, `map str` is better than `map #(str % %2)`.  You should avoid declaring new functions when you can just pass an existing one in directly.

Comment: @Mark: agreed, rewrote to remove unnecessary anonymous function entirely.